# Лучший способ подсчета времени в течении которого переменная не изменялась. C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Добрый день. Есть ли какой нибудь красивый способ отслеживания времени в течении которого переменная не изменяла свое значение? На данный момент я реализовал это каким то мерзким костылем.

```
        private double _zpreventValue;
        private readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer _zcontrolTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        private readonly System.Windows.Forms.Timer _downtimeTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        private TimeSpan _downtime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,0);

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            _zcontrolTimer.Tick += _ZcontrolTimer_Tick;
            _zcontrolTimer.Interval = 5000;

            _downtimeTimer.Tick += _downtimeTimer_Tick;
            _downtimeTimer.Interval = 1000;  
        }

        private void _downtimeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_zcontrolTimer.Enabled)
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _zcontrolTimer.Stop()));
            _downtime = _downtime + new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => digitalGauge8.Text = _downtime.ToString()));

            using (var db = new VstecEntities())
            {
                 db.DownTimes.Single(item => item.Date == DateTime.Today).MachineDownTime = _downtime;
                 db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void _ZcontrolTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var db = new VstecEntities())
            {
                if (db.DownTimes.Count(item => item.Date == DateTime.Today) == 0)
                {
                    db.DownTimes.Add(new DownTime
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Today,
                        MachineDownTime = _downtime
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                
            }

            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _downtimeTimer.Start()));
        }

private void SomeFunc()
{
            if (Math.Abs(someValue - _zpreventValue) <= 0.0)
            {                
                if (!_zcontrolTimer.Enabled && !_downtimeTimer.Enabled)
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _zcontrolTimer.Start()));
            }
            else
            {
                _zpreventValue = someValue;
                if (_zcontrolTimer.Enabled)
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _zcontrolTimer.Stop()));
                if (_downtimeTimer.Enabled)
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _downtimeTimer.Stop()));
            }    
}
```

Есть функция в которую прилетает какое то значение. Если значение равно значению переменной, то запускается таймер, который ожидает 5 секунд и после чего запускает еще один таймер(мрак) который начинает отсчет времени в течении которого переменная не изменяет своего значения. Как только значение переменной меняется, таймер останавливается и все по новой.

Есть ли какой нибудь более элегантный способ? А то смотря на свои каракули хочется плакать :(

Comment: я не понял какую именно _переменную_ ты сейчас отслеживаешь. Больше похоже, что ты замеряешь время между вызовами функции

Comment: Отслеживаю переменную someValue. Которая прилетает в функцию SomeFunc

Comment: Тогда не понял что ты делаешь в таймерах

Comment: В функцию SomeFunc прилетает переменная someValue . Значение переменной someValue присваивается переменной _zpreventValue. На следующей итерации если значение переменной someValue равно значению переменной _zpreventValue, то значение переменной someValue  считается не измененным - запускается первый таймер, который, так сказать, дает 5 секунд переменной для того что бы она поменяла свое значение. Если нет Запускается второй таймер который уже считает время сколько значение не менялось. Как только переменная меняется таймер останавливается.

Comment: Насколько высокая точность требуется?

Comment: Высокой точности не требуется. Время между фактическим и подсчитанным в пределах суток может разниться на 1-5 минут - ничего страшного.

Comment: Почему не сделать свойство и дергать метод при изменении?

Comment: Это все равно будет два таймера. Хотя код станет по красивее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На мой взгляд, достаточно завести свойство и счетчик времени к этому свойству. Счетчик перезапускается в момент изменения свойства.

```
class Test {
    private Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    private int someValue;
    public int SomeValue {
        get { return someValue; }
        set {
            if (someValue != value) {
                someValue = value;
                OnSomeValueChanged();
            }
        }
     }

     private OnSomeValueChanged() {
         stopwatch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"Свойство SomeValue не менялось {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} миллисекунд.");
         stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     }
}
```

При желании обобщить решение для разных свойств можно сделать реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`, подписаться на событие и завести, например, словарь с таймерами.

UPD

Добавил пример для нескольких свойств с запоминанием временных меток (по предложению @Андрей):

```
class Test
{
    private readonly stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> labels = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private str someValue1;
    public string SomeValue1
    {
        get => someValue1;
        set
        {
            if (someValue1 != value)
            {
                someValue1 = value;
                HandlePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private str someValue2;
    public string SomeValue2
    {
        get => someValue2;
        set
        {
            if (someValue2 != value)
            {
                someValue2 = value;
                HandlePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandlePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        // если не нашли метку в словаре, то это свойство еще не менялось
        int lastLabel;
        if (!labels.TryGetValue(propertyName, out lastLabel))
        {
            lastLabel = 0;
        }

        // запоминаем текущую метку
        var currentLabel = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        // получаем временной промежуток
        Console.WriteLine($"Прошло {currentLabel - lastLabel} миллисекунд.");

        // устанавливаем новую метку
        labels[propertyName] = currentLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше, имхо, таймер один, а в словаре хранить временные метки

Comment: Отличный вариант. Единственное что в данном случае отсчет времени запускается сразу при изменении переменной, не давая задержки в X секунд на возможность ее изменения.

Comment: @Андрей, кстати, да. Неплохой вариант.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЦарев, ну так вы записывайте значение в свойство не сразу, а когда пользователь нажал "Применить" или типа того